# laravel scout searchable trait

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-scout

I added the `Laravel\Scout\Searchable` trait to the model to make it searchable, this is my model

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Business extends Model
{
    use Searchable;
    protected $table = 'business';
    public function searchableAs()
    {
        return 'business_index';
    }
}
```

I'm using vue js with axios, when I'm posting a request via axios the request time become 2.76s~, but when i commented the use searchable like this

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Business extends Model
{
    //use Searchable;
    protected $table = 'business';
    public function searchableAs()
    {
        return 'business_index';
    }
}
```

the request time became 300ms~ only,

is there any way to make a request faster without compromising the `use Searchable` ?

Comment: Did you set up a queue driver as recommended in the docs? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scout A lot of time might now be spent on making indexes

Comment: yes sir im using tntsearch as my search driver

Comment: other request method is slow like delete, post , put etc. when i use the use Searchable

Answer (score 0):

You should set up queuing for Laravel Scout so it can process this in the background using Redis or something, which will stop your actual requests being slow.

Enable Queueing on Scout:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scout#queueing

**config/scout.php** configuration file to true:

```
'queue' => true,
```

Queue Setup:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues